# Loadable Kernel Module & Notification Manager

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I've successfully created and installed a loadable kernel module for my development phone.

Does anyone know how to make a status bar notification to the user (i.e. Notification / NotificationManager) from the kernel?

I understand how to create a service and use Notification / NotificationManager to generate a status bar notification. But how do you make a notification when the event is in the kernel? I'm having a problem bridging the gap.

A similar functionality I'm trying to achieve is like connecting to the phone via USB. When the phone detects a USB connection, a status bar notification is produced (and if debugging is enabled, it will tell you that too). How is this done? At some point the kernel sends a signal, but how is the notification generated?

The approach I'm going to try and implement is using the NDK. Create a library that listens/waits for a signal from my LKM, then use then create an app that's just a background service that notifies when the signal is received.

Is there a more elegant solution for this? And I'd like to not have to recompile the AOSP.

Thanks!